# Google Pub/Sub Retry timeout error with Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Goole Pub/Sub for a message processing in my appliction(csv parser and message contains file details). It loops every 30 seconds to check for new messages.
After few minutes of start somewhere in 600th loop I start getting this error-

> Error: Retry total timeout exceeded before anyresponse was received at
>   repeat
>   (/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/node_modules/google-gax/lib/api_callable.js:223:11)
>   at Timeout._onTimeout
>   (/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/node_modules/google-gax/lib/api_callable.js:265:13)
>   at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11) at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5) at
>   listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5) at Timer.processTimers
>   (timers.js:223:10)

Below is my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "googleapis": "^45.0.0",
    "csv-parse": "^4.8.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "knex": "^0.20.8",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^7.11.0",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "google-gax": "1.6.2",
    "winston": "^3.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "~0.19.0"
  }
```

I have tried updating to latest gax but of no use.

Here is my listener program copied off and edited from Google's own examples.

```
const maxMessageFileLimit = process.env.MAX_PARALLEL_PULLS * process.env.MAX_CONCURRENT_MESSAGES;
let currentMessageFileCount = 0;

function startListener(
  projectId = process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  subscriptionName = process.env.SUBSCRIPTION_NAME
) {
  const {
    v1
  } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
  const subClient = new v1.SubscriberClient(); // Creates a client; cache this for further use.

  async function synchronousPull() {
    const formattedSubscription = subClient.subscriptionPath(
      projectId,
      subscriptionName
    );

    const request = {
      subscription: formattedSubscription,
      maxMessages: process.env.MAX_CONCURRENT_MESSAGES || 1, // The maximum number of messages returned for this request.
    };
    const [response] = await subClient.pull(request);

    if (response && response.receivedMessages.length) {
     //some work happens here in await
     //along with acknowledging the messages ASAP

     }

}

  setInterval(() => { //loop to restart pulling messages once the worker is not busy
    if ((maxMessageFileLimit - currentMessageFileCount) >= process.env.MAX_CONCURRENT_MESSAGES) {
      synchronousPull().catch(console.error); //run next pull request only when worker is free enough
    }
  }, process.env.PULL_INTERVAL || 30000);
}

startListener();
```

Code works fine, It is just the error that constantly keeps hogging my logs and error reporting in GCP that I am worried about. 
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest Cloud Pub/Sub client library?

Comment: Yes I did to 1.5.0 but it said `Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded`. thus reverted back.

Comment: Is it that every call after that also gets a deadline exceeded or that it occurs on calls once in awhile?

Comment: If it does not receive any response in any call then it shows `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`.

Comment: So you get a `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` on one of the calls. But what happens on a subsequent call to `pull`?

Comment: In every pull there is same response unless I have some messages in my Pub/sub.